# How do I select entire words with Tmux's mouse mode?

Tags: mouse, tmux

The default tmux mouse mode seems to select words by character -- this is a little too granular for me; if I click [or double-click] in the middle of a word, I'd like it to start selecting the entire word.

Are there any ways to accomplish this? Thanks much!

Answer (score 7):

Hold `Shift` and double-click the text. This sends the mouse input directly to the terminal (xterm, terminal, etc) and bypasses tmux's mouse mode.

Note: I tested this in xterm and gnome-terminal. For other terminals you may need to hold a different modifier key.

Comment: Sorry, that uses the terminal's selection, not tmux's selection buffer. Nice trick though, thanks -- it seems with kde's konsole you can use that to click on a link with tmux's mouse mode on.

Comment: Glad it helps :) Why does the distinction matter to you? I use `tmux set-option -g set-clipboard on` so tmux's selection buffer is always copied to the system clipboard, then I can mostly forget that tmux has its own selection buffer.

Comment: @Newtonx, what if you're sshed into another system and using tmux there?

Comment: Yeah, and in my case, I often have vertically-split panes, so copying without tmux means you copy some mishmesh garbage from both panes.

Comment: For iTerm2 on Mac, use "alt" as the modifier

Comment: In Mac's default terminal app, this seems to be fn key

Comment: I'm downvoting cause I understand this is a workaround and not a solution.Meanwhile, there is a valid answer by Steve Ward, although it could be better written, with examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify which characters are considered word separators with the `word-separators` option.
Its default value is  `-_@`.

Comment: finally an answer that actually works! Thanks to this I was able to find [this example](https://github.com/mmerickel/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf), so adding `setw -g word-separators ' @"=()[]'` and `setw -ag word-separators "'"` to my `.tmux.conf` finally gave me the selection I wanted! I wish I could upvote more than once, thanks Steve!

Answer (score 2):

not without patching your tmux source code, sorry. hopefully such a feature can be added to tmux in the future

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [xtmux](https://github.com/dylex/xtmux) could do that, but that won't apply over ssh. The iTerm equivalent of `Shift` is `Alt`. I haven't found a pure tmux solution, but you might consider vim mode copy/paste:

`set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'Escape' copy-selection`

With that and `set -g mode-mouse on`, you can click and hold at the beginning of your selection, hit `w` and other vim commands until you have what you want selected, and then release.