# How do I use tmux 2.4's double/triple click to select text with bash/iTerm2?

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux, iterm2

Following on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/598718/how-do-i-select-entire-words-with-tmuxs-mouse-mode) from 2013 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404140/can-i-use-double-click-to-select-and-copy-in-tmux-like-in-iterm2) from 2015, has anyone identified how to use [tmux 2.4](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES)'s new `Support for mouse double and triple clicks` to select text without modifier keys? I'm specifically interested in how to do this with bash / iTerm2.

Merely moving from tmux 2.3 to 2.4 does not change double-click (non-)behavior.